Unexpected token in PowerShell with GitHub Actions
I have the following GitHub Actions step:
- name: Test build with powershell
  if: runner.os == 'Windows'
  shell: pwsh
  run: |
    Set-PSDebug -Trace 1
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" src/li.vcxproj -nologo -clp:DisableConsoleColor -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=x64 -p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets="C:\Fortify\Core\private-bin\sca\MSBuildPlugin\Fortify.targets"

When I run my workflow, I get this error:
ParserError: C:\actions-runner\_work\_temp\18c38524-eb14-47cb-8494-13adcb59a93e.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  … 19\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" src/li.vcxproj -nologo …
     |                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unexpected token 'src/li.vcxproj' in expression or statement.

I tried changing my quoting around the MSBuild.exe path to use single quotes rather than double quotes, but I get the same error with both quotes.
Why is the token considered unexpected, and how can I fix my syntax?

In short: Targeting an executable (including .ps1 files and batch files) by a name or path that is quoted or contains variable references must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with &, the call operator; see the linked duplicate for details.
